# Node.js: Capture STDOUT of `child_process.spawn`

Tags: javascript, node.js, stream

I need to capture in a custom **stream** outputs of a spawned child process.

```
child_process.spawn(command[, args][, options])
```

For example,

```
var s = fs.createWriteStream('/tmp/test.txt');
child_process.spawn('ifconfig', [], {stdio: [null, s, null]})
```

Now how do I read from the `/tmp/test.txt` in real time?

It looks like `child_process.spawn` is not using `stream.Writable.prototype.write` nor `stream.Writable.prototype._write` for its execution.

For example,

```
s.write = function() { console.log("this will never get printed"); };
```

As well as,

```
s.__proto__._write = function() { console.log("this will never get printed"); };
```

It looks like it uses file descriptors *under-the-hood* to write from `child_process.spawn` to a file.

Doing this does not work:

```
var s2 = fs.createReadStream('/tmp/test.txt');
s2.on("data", function() { console.log("this will never get printed either"); });
```

So, how can I get the `STDOUT` contents of a child process?

What I want to achieve is to stream `STDOUT` of a child process to a socket. If I provide the socket directly to the `child_process.spawn` as a `stdio` parameter it closes the socket when it finishes, but I want to keep it open.

**Update:**

The solution is to use default `{stdio: ['pipe', 'pipe', 'pipe']}` options and listen to the created `.stdout` of the child process.

```
var cmd = child_process.spaw('ifconfig');
cmd.stdout.on("data", (data) => { ... });
```

Now, to up the ante, a more challenging question:

-- How do you read the `STDOUT` of the child process and still preserve the colors?

For example, if you send `STDOUT` to `process.stdout` like so:

```
child_process.spawn('ifconfig', [], {stdio: [null, process.stdout, null]});
```

it will keep the colors and print colored output to the console, because the `.isTTY` property is set to `true` on `process.stdout`.

```
process.stdout.isTTY // true
```

Now if you use the default `{stdio: ['pipe', 'pipe', 'pipe']}`, the data you will read will be stripped of console colors. How do you get the colors?

One way to do that would be creating your own custom stream with `fs.createWriteStream`, because `child_process.spawn` requires your streams to have a file descriptor.

Then setting `.isTTY` of that stream to `true`, to preserve colors.

And finally you would need to capture the data what `child_process.spawn` writes to that stream, but since `child_process.spawn` does not use `.prototype.write` nor `.prototype._write` of the stream, you would need to capture its contents in some other *hacky* way.

That's probably why `child_process.spawn` requires your stream to have a file descriptor because it bypasses the `.prototype.write` call and writes directly to the file *under-the-hood*.

Any ideas how to implement this?

Answer (score 8):

You can do it without using a temporary file:

```
var process = child_process.spawn(command[, args][, options]);
process.stdout.on('data', function (chunk) {
    console.log(chunk);
});
```

Comment: Does this actually block the output stream between the statements, or is any output in that interval lost?

Comment: @AsadSaeeduddin no, it doesn't block.

Answer (score 4):

Hi I'm on my phone but I will try to guide you as I can. I will clarify when near a computer if needed

What I think you want is to read the `stdout` from a spawn and do something with the data?

You can give the spawn a variable name instead of just running the function, e.g:

```
var child = spawn();
```

Then listen to the output like:

```
child.stdout.on('data', function(data) {
    console.log(data.toString());
});
```

You could use that to write the data then to a file or whatever you may want to do with it.

Comment: Thanks, for the fast reply!

Answer (score 3):

The `stdio` option requires file descriptors, not stream objects, so one way to do it is use use `fs.openSync()` to create an output file descriptor and us that.

Taking your first example, but using `fs.openSync()`:

```
var s = fs.openSync('/tmp/test.txt', 'w');
var p = child_process.spawn('ifconfig', [], {stdio: [process.stdin, s, process.stderr]});
```

You could also set both stdout and stderr to the same file descriptor (for the same effect as bash's `2>&1`).

You'll need to close the file when you are done, so:

```
p.on('close', function(code) {
  fs.closeSync(s);
  // do something useful with the exit code ...
});
```