# How to intercept and save to a variable the output streaming of a command in node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, stream, spawn

I have this script that properly run synchronously the `ls` command and output the result to the terminal. How can I intercept the result and save it to a variable?

```
const cp = require('child_process');
const result = cp.spawnSync(
    'ls',
    ['-l', '/usr'],
    { stdio: [process.stdin, process.stdout, process.stdout] }
);
```

If I try this, as suggested by https://stackoverflow.com/a/30617874/693271

```
result.stdout.on('data', function (chunk) {
    console.log(chunk);
});
```

I get

```
result.stdout.on('data', function (chunk) {
              ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'on' of null
```

The difference is that is about `spawnSync` and not about `spawn`

Comment: Please [search](/search?q=%5Bnode.js%5D+capture+child+stream) before posting. More about searching [here](/help/searching).

Comment: I found stuff for `spawn` but not for `spawnSync` yet. Keep searching

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By looking at the [docs](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_spawnsync_command_args_options) we can see that the result of `spawnSync` returns an object containing a key called `stdout`, which is a `Buffer`. You do not have to listen to events since you're calling the synchronous version of the `spawn` - the process will wait for the command to finish executing before resuming and then returns the result.

So in your case, the result of your `ls -l /usr` command can be read with `result.stdout.toString()`. You also need to keep the default config for `stdio` in the options.

Comment: I am getting `Cannot read property 'toString' of null`, I wonder what I am doing wrong...

Comment: I tried your code, and it works if you don't specify any custom `stdio` config (removed the options altogether)